# How to adjust height of UITableViewCell in swift for the below screenshot

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I am new to swift. I am unable to adjust the height uitaleviewcell dynamically. 
Image & collectionview will be visible based on the condition. Below reply section will be visible after clicking on 'Button'. Can anyone plz help me in achieving this task. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1- use dynamic tableView like that in viewDidLoad

```
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400;

 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

2- don't implement hightforCellAtIndexpath

3- adjust constraints properly in cell xib from top to bottom

4- regarding the collectionview , imageView and reply section give them all a height constraint of zero initially then, hook the height constraint for each on as IBOulet and change it's constant value in **cellForRowAtIndexpath** according to the current item manage the hide/show by changing the corresponding constant value of the constraint

5- before return cell do this

```
 cell.layoutSubviews()

 cell.layoutIfNeeded()

 return cell
```

so cell can be relayouted to reflect the change of it's subviews's constraints

Comment: thanks for replying..@sh_khan, can you provide me a sample project

Comment: see this http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-automatic-row-height/

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried This ?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

And in DidLoad

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

if still Its not Adjusted try calling Methods of layouts after you deque a cell

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.reloadSubviews()
```

Comment: it did not helped, I am using swift3. can you plz provide me a sample project. That will clear my understanding. iamsinghaloke@gmail.com plz mail me if possible. thanks